# Why is my bold text not quite bold in Chrome, OSX?

Tags: support, bug, design

Mac OSX, 10.7.4. Running Chrome.

[image]

As you can see, my bold text is... not very bold. There *is* a little difference though.

Happens to me in SciFi.SE only. SO is fine.

I tested with Safari, and it actually works, so perhaps it is a Chrome problem.

Why is this?

**EDIT**

User *phantom42* provided a good comparison of Chrome (top) and Firefox (bottom) on OSX:

[image]

Comment: Normal *Italics* **Bold** ***Bold Italics***

Comment: Here in Firefox 19 on Windows 7, bold looks bold.

Comment: @Keen: Curiously, your comment's **bold** text does look **bold** to me (although it is a little bit hard to identify). I suppose this occurs on question/answer preview only then.

Comment: It looks okay in Chrome on Windows (in Question preview; on main site it looks good; on meta, a little less bold, but still noticeable).

Comment: A similar question occurs [here](http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/google-chrome-browser-fonts-problem-on-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Looks fuzzy in Chromium on Ubuntu, but normal and bold are still much more easily distinguishable than on that screenshot of Keen's comment...

Comment: I'm kind of inclined to blame Chrome for this one... but, now it's been about a month which means a billion new Chrome versions. Is this still an issue with the latest stable Chrome?

Comment: @AnnaLear: Yes, the current version (25.0.1364.172 wtf...) presents the same issues. If only we could get another OSX Chrome user...

Comment: This sounds like a font issue, rather than (or maybe in addition to) a browser problem. Inspecting the page reveals the following font declaration: `font-family: 'VarelaRoundRegular','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`. Maybe you don't have any of the listed fonts (although the first one is a web font, so theoretically that shouldn't matter...) and your fallback sans-serif font is just too bold-looking?

Comment: here you go. [chrome vs ff on osx](http://i.imgur.com/aKAKLUb.png) - top: chrome 25.0.1364.172. bottom: ff 19.0.2 - it's definitely harder to make out the difference in chrome.

Comment: @phantom42: Thanks! That's a much better comparison image. I'll update the question with it.